# Dismissing a UINavigationController and Presenting another UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a two view controllers, `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`, embedded in a `UINavigationController`. `ViewControllerA` has a `UICollectionView` that displays images.

When the camera icon located at index 0 and the `UICollectionViewCell` is selected, it should dismiss `ViewControllerA` and display `ViewControllerB`. And also, there is a `ViewController` that presents `ViewControllerA` modally

This is what I've done, but it only dismiss `ViewControllerA` and nothing happens

```
let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("cameraViewController") as! UINavigationController
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            self.presentingViewController?.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Comment: Is `presentingViewController` nil?

Comment: It's not throwing any error. I debugged it by adding a breakPoint. It ran the code just didn't react to it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857274/uinavigationcontroller-presenting-view-controller-while-dismissing-another-cont?rq=1

Comment: It wouldn't throw an error if it was nil, because you're using `self.presentingViewController?` instead of `self.presentingViewController!`, if it is nil, that is most likely the cause of the problem - try printing `self.presentingViewController` and see what the result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When view controller is dismissed, my guess is `self` is already deallocated so `self.presentingViewController?` becomes `nil` too. I would create a strong reference to presenting view controller right before dismissing action takes place:

```
let presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { completed in
  if completed {
    presentingViewController?.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Also, make sure `self.presentingViewController` is not `nil` in the first place.

Comment: Saw this somewhere. But, overlooked it that it'll be the cause of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing is happening is because `self.presentingViewController?` is nil.

If instead, you were using `self.presentingViewController!`, there would be an error stating *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value*, which should always be avoided.

You are correct in using `self.presentingViewController?` instead of `self.presentingViewController!`, as it is much safer, but in order to fix this, you must make sure that `self.presentingViewController?` is not nil.

```
let presenting = self.presentingViewController

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {() -> Void in
    presenting?.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```